# How to improve Solaris Server Configuration

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, server

As a programmer I have limited knowledge of the ins and outs of Hardware configuration.  I've been tasked with assisting in server tuning.  I understand tuning a server for peek performance varies per environment.  However, there must be basic or ideal options to consider when attempting to improve server performance.  So far I have tested many JVM options and analyzed Garbage collection.  I have also tested application(JAVA) performance by setting different memory sizes.  What else should I consider when improving server performance?

Comment: You ***should*** *ask* this on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). However, *basic* configuration tuning is going to depend on your expected usage. Is your application IO bound? CPU bound?

Comment: Thanks.  Will do.  I would say I/O bound since it's basically a read write application